# Any real software to let me access perma-locked iPhone 4s data?

Tags: iphone, ios

Ok, I'm going insane over this. I refuse to believe there are ZERO ways to access the data on a locked iPhone 4s running ios 7.1 or so.

I recently found my old iPhone which I was ecstatic about because it contains literally thousands of personal photos, videos and voice memos.

I have no idea what the password is anymore.

There must be some kind of third party open source type program that will let me access the data on my PC, right? it seems like google only provides sponsored remedies and I cant find any real information. I found lots of none free programs that claim they can get in like this: https://www.imyfone.com/ios-data-erase/how-to-unlock-iphone-without-passcode/
But I dont know how legit they are.

I DONT want to restore the phone.

I'll even write my own program that accesses data from iphone 4, If someone can point me in the right direction. ios 7's gotta have lots of known exploits by now.

I really want the data on that device thank you.

Comment: You don't have any iTunes backups from the phone? They can be easily read... If you synced the phone to iTunes on your PC before, you may be able to back it up without unlocking it on iOS 7 - I can't remember when that changed.